# share screenshot label. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, share, controller, app

Я делюсь контентом(скрин UILabel) в приложении через UIActivityController.
Все работает кроме того что скриншот выходит кривой. Оно делает скрин  не Label, а лезет в сторону и обрезает даже.
Как я могу это исправить ?

Вот мой код контроллера.

```
@IBAction func shareContent(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someLabel.bounds.size)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        var imagesToShare = [AnyObject]()
        imagesToShare.append(image!)

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagesToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, ведь вы рендерите сам лейбл, а не какое-то вью

```
someLabel.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне это помогло.